# Binding Selected Rows from Multiple Data Files in R

Tags: r, rbind

I have written code to previously generate time series data from a model for multiple files.  I need the full time series data in general, but I also want to read in the results for all columns from specific days and combine them into a separate file.  However, when I do this, I get "Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match" despite the fact that I know for a fact all files should have the same column names and # of columns.

I tried the approach here [Select multiple rows in multiple DFs with loop in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33172886/select-multiple-rows-in-multiple-dfs-with-loop-in-r) but I got the error "Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match"

```
Resfiles = list.files("C:/Users/Me/Desktop/R Code/Testfiles", pattern = "Results+.*csv")
Resfiles
```

is how I am reading in the files

Approach 1:

```
resfiles.list = sapply(Resfiles, function(file)
{df = read.csv(file, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df$SourceFile = file
enddate = nrow(file)
df = df[c(1,2,21,133,159,enddate), ]




}
 )

allres = do.call(rbind, resfiles.list)
```

generates the error  "Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match"

and Approach 2:

```
Results = NULL;

for(j in Resfiles)
{

  input = read.csv(file = j, header = TRUE, sep =",")
  enddate = nrow(input)

  d0 = input[1, ]
  d0
  d1 = input[2, ]
  d20 = input[21,]
  d132=input[133, ]
  d158 = input[159, ]
  final = input[enddate, ]
  final

  results1o = rbind(d0, d1, d20, d132, d158, final)
  Results = rbind(Results,results1o )
  print(Results)
}
write.csv(Results, file = "PredResults.csv")
```

When I try Approach 2 with smartbind instead I get the error "Error in !sapply(data, function(l) is.null(l) | (ncol(l) == 0) | (nrow(l) ==  : 
  invalid argument type"

If I just use rbind, I get "Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  first five rows are empty: giving up"

What I would like to get is a data frame with the specific rows of interest grouped by animal that I can later subset and process as needed. I just need to be able to read in these 40-odd results files, extract the rows needed all into one big data frame, and save that as a csv and I need it extensible so that the same code will work whether I have 40ish files or >100.

Comment: Please include some reproducible data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: It would just be a CSV with columns like "Animal ID", "Feed Intake", "Body Weight" etc - about 20 columns in total.  What I don't get is why despite all data files being the same in terms of structure it says they do not match?  They're all generated with the same identical process....